# map location latlng as undefined in useEffect on React Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am getting a TypeError when trying to invoke a location event when the map loads in React Leaflet. When I make this a click event via useMapEffects, it works. The "load" event with useMapEffects does not work (and gives the same error). So I tried to refactor into useEffect. Same error.

When trying to make it on load it gives this error.

The Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: latlng is undefined
    project Projection.SphericalMercator.js:24
    latLngToPoint CRS.js:28
    project Map.js:982
    latLngToLayerPoint Map.js:1004
    _project CircleMarker.js:72
    _reset Path.js:139
    onAdd Path.js:85
    _layerAdd Layer.js:114
    whenReady Map.js:1477
    addLayer Layer.js:172
    addLayer layer.js:9
    React 8
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
...etc
```

My component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useMap, useMapEvents, CircleMarker } from "react-leaflet";

const CurrentLocation = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null);

  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    map.locate().on("locationfound", (e) => {
      const pos = [e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng];
      console.log(pos);
      setPosition(pos);
      map.flyTo(pos, map.getZoom());
    });
  }, [map]);

  return position === null ? null : (
    <CircleMarker position={position}></CircleMarker>
  );
};

export default CurrentLocation;
```

My console log actually produces an array with the correct coordinates.

My component invoked on my main map:

```
...
import CurrentLocation from "../CurrentLocation/CurrentLocation";

const MainMap = (props) => {
  ...

  return (
    <div>
      <MapContainer
        style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}
        zoom={12}
        center={centerOfMap}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <CurrentLocation />
        ...
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with CircleMarker. It doesn't have "position", it has a "center."